# Custom Function for SEO by Yoast plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, functions

We use a very customized version of WordPress for some of our index/root site pages where we use a custom meta box for custom permalinks. What we are looking for is a custom function that basically looks to see if the custom permalink field is being used and if it is, to grab that as the canonical url. This helps with duplicate content being indexed by search engines and we're gearing up to use Outbrain, who will be crawling our canonical urls.

I came across this post on Stack Overflow but am not sure how to edit for my needs.

```
function design_canonical() {
   global $post;

   if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'design' ) {
       return site_url( '/design/' . $post->post_name );
   } else {
       // Leave blank and Yoast SEO will use default canonical for posts/pages
   }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'design_canonical' )
```

I'm thinking the `post->ID` doesn't need the `'design'` and the `return site_url` should be my custom meta box. How to edit it properly?

Comment: What have you tried or where has your research led? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: I came across this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12493375/setting-a-custom-canonical-url-in-yoast-wordpress-seo-plugin) but am not sure how to customize it for my needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is [`get_post_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) instead of `get_post_type`

This:

```
if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'design' ) {
```

Should be:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'your-meta-key',true);
if (!empty($meta)) {
```

Put altogether

```
function design_canonical_wpse_93717() {
   global $post;
   $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'your-meta-key',true);
   if (!empty($meta)) {
       return $meta; // assuming this is an absolute URL
   }
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'design_canonical_wpse_93717' );
```

The `else` conditional was spurious so I removed it, and I am assuming that the filter works as advertised. I don't use WP-SEO.

Also, I am a bit concerns as usually filters work more like this:

```
function design_canonical_wpse_93717($url) {
   global $post;
   $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'your-meta-key',true);
   if (!empty($meta)) {
       $url = $meta; // assuming this is an absolute URL
   }
   return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'design_canonical_wpse_93717' );
```

That is, usually filters pull in content via a parameter and pass that content back out, but again I don't use that plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

On Edit:
Works a treat. I put the else function back in for pages/posts that don't use the custom permalink. I'll just have to find one of those in our site to make sure that works.

Comment: So, I just checked a page and it isn't showing the canonical link at all (the pages def use the WP generated permalink).

`function design_canonical_wpse_93717() {
   global $post;
   $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_pbsparents_cp',true);
   if (!empty($meta)) {
       return $meta; // assuming this is an absolute URL
   } else {
        // Leave blank and Yoast SEO will use default canonical for posts/pages
    }
}
    add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'design_canonical_wpse_93717' );`

Comment: Put `return 'this-is-a-test';` immediately after the opening `{` and see if that prints to the page.

Comment: Actually, I just placed your second function into the functions file and it seems to be working for both instances. I'm getting the custom meta field and when there isn't one, I'm getting the WP permalink. So, it appears as though it's working properly! Thanks so much.

Comment: That is why I was worried about the format of that answer you found.

Comment: You were obviously right to be concerned. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I don't see this as working - it adjusts the canonical in question but all other pages get no canonical. It seems there needs to be something for "else" to cover the other situations, something to call the default functionality.